# Install and Run separate,second Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I wanted to have several different chrome instances on my PC.. and i had to install  **CHROME**, **CHROME** **CANARY**,  **CHROMIUM** versions separately, and did a good JOB !

however, does there exists built-in function for "CHROME" only, not to install other Chrome versions?

Comment: This should probably an answer, it's hard to tell here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might also look at Chrome's "User Profiles" feature.  It's a really neat way to separate multiple Facebook/Gmail/etc accounts.  It also keeps distinct bookmarks / browse history / autocomplete / cookies / etc.  Pretty much the only thing shared is the build of Chrome that you are running.

And there's a really nice profile swapping icon in the upper right corner:

[image: Note the right-hand-corner profile icons]

Navigate to "chrome://settings"  --> "Users"

Update(2015): Note, that this feature was borked up recently, so to get the good behavior now requires setting some extra flags.  See http://digiwonk.wonderhowto.com/how-to/get-back-avatars-chrome-switch-user-profiles-more-easily-0159605/

Comment: I never even knew this existed.  This was super helpful and exactly what I needed.